# changing / setting UID of IMAP entries for mails

Tags: email, python, imap

I want to set custom uid for mails - is this possible?

Background:
I want to backup mails from an internal mail server (`Mailcow) to an external one (`IONOS). I am using python `imaplib` package and adding the mails to the external server using `append function which can also set flags like` \SEEN`. (Maybe questions about the specific implementation would be better posted at stackoverflow). This works but has at least two major drawbacks:

1. Need to track a list / database: I need to track list of mails already been copied for deleting mails on the target which has been deleted on the source and avoiding double copying.
2. Speed: Especially synchronizing the flags takes very long (maybe this would be faster using a library for a compiled language such as POCO or karastojko/mailio)

In addition spaces in mail directory name and localization cause a lot of trouble (directory name translations, converting to UTF7, placing "") .

If a could set the same UID per directory on the target server than on the source server I would a least need no list tracking. As a know only the UID is unique (per directory) - the message ID not.

Unfortunately
A) Mailcow can only synchronizing mail from another server but not to.
B) `imapsync/imapsync`seams not be updated anymore and I have not managed to run it up to now (failed with `Can't locate IO/Tee.pm in @INC` after installing already a lot of missing perl packages).